# Importing autobahn with webpack & babel

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I am trying to import the library "autobahn" in my project using babel and webpack. I can import the minified/compiled web version of the library in the project, however importing the npm installed package provides http://pastebin.com/LWfL0m85. Namely the error:

```
ERROR in ./~/autobahn/package.json
Module parse failed: /~snip~/web/node_modules/autobahn/package.json Unexpected token (2:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Is there a way to debug this further? Given the error, I cannot determine what is the best plan of action for me to troubleshoot this. Ultimately, I would like to stay away from async module loaders and keep webpack's flattening module loader if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The way autobahn is built, when you require the library it will attempt to load it's package.json, [see line 17](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-js/blob/master/package/lib/autobahn.js).

You need to add the [json-loader](https://github.com/webpack/json-loader) to your webpack.config.js so Webpack will be able to parse this file.